# SSIS remote execution with relative paths in C#

Tags: c#, ssis, relative-path

I'm trying to execute a remote (Driver package) that in turn executes an SSIS package.

I am using the using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime namespace for this and the below code.

```
var app = new Application();
var pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null, true);
pkg.ImportConfigurationFile(configfilePath);

var pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
{
    isPackageExecuted = true;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the remote driver packages has a config file associated with it that uses relative paths. When I execute the driver from my Dev machine we are running from a different folder structure to the deployed Driver/SSIS packages. So I can successfully call the driver but it doesnt find the local packages as its using its local machine starting address as the starting point on the remote server which doesnt exist there.

e.g.

Dev Machine

C:\Code\TFS\Test\SSIS\assembly.dll

Remote Machine

C:\Driver\Configs
C:\Driver\Packages

When I call the remote machine it taking "C:\Code\TFS\Test\SSIS" as its starting point and then using relative paths to look for SSIS packages and its failing to find them.

Has anyone got a work around to this or an alternative way?

---

Update, I sorted the problem by executing psexec from system internals that allows you to set the working directory of the remote machine to handle the relative paths correctly. I then invoked psexec from my C# code using Process.Start ets... passing in the command line execution values

---

Comment: I don't know if this will help but you can add the path of the config file to an environment variable so that it can be different on all the machines you are using

Comment: Interesting, so how would it work? We call a remote package and specify a config file location but the environment variable would overwrite this? Thanks

Comment: Exactly, You can also specify the full path of the config file by right clicking on the designer and selecting configuration, there are a couple of different options there?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1405 as well as this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671628.aspx Please let me know if this helped so that I can make it the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link mate, it does help but I don't think it solves my problem :( I havent got access to change the Driver/Packages on the remote machine as they are 3rd part, we just execute them but they use relative paths.

Comment: Ah oraait, wel, the best way(only way I can think of) would then be to execute the package with DtExec and specify the configuration File with /Configuration, that should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx

Comment: Thanks mate, yea I did look at that, I think we might execute a batch file on the remote system and then use psexec -w to set the working directory so the relative paths work, testing now. Otherwise I will try the DtExec, appreciate the help!

Comment: No Worries, let me know if you came right

Comment: Thanks mate, we got around the issue using psexec -w to set the remote working directory, psexec is invoke from C#...

Comment: cool, glad you came right and thanks for responding, I suggest you add what you did as an answer for future so users :-)

Comment: If you've found the solution post it as an **answer** rather than updating the question. Then after a couple of days you can accept it so that everyone (including the system) knows you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Package.ImportConfigurationFile will happily take an absolute path (as shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.importconfigurationfile.aspx), which will let you avoid the relative path issue (as long as you know the remote machine folder structure, that is).